# Jest - mock a property and function from moment-timezone

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Im trying to mock property `tz` and a function using jest but i dont know to mock both things together:

If run something like:

```
jest.mock('moment-timezone', () => () => ({weekday: () => 5}))

jest.mock('moment-timezone', () => {
  return {
    tz: {

    }
  }
})
```

I can mock attribute `tz` or instruction `moment()`. How can i write a mock for cover this code?

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

module.exports.send = () => {
  const now = moment()
  moment.tz.setDefault('America/Sao_Paulo')
  return now.weekday()
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could take advantage of the second parameter of [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options), which would let you specify a custom implementation of the mocked module to use in testing.

Inside this custom implementation, you can also define some convenience helpers to emulate expected implementation values (e.g. `weekday()`).

```
// send-module.test.js

jest.mock('moment-timezone', () => {
    let weekday
    const moment = jest.fn(() => {
        return {
            weekday: jest.fn(() => weekday),
        }
    })
    moment.tz = {
        setDefault: jest.fn(),
    }
    // Helper for tests to set expected weekday value
    moment.__setWeekday = (value) => weekday = value
    return moment;
})

const sendModule = require('./send-module')

test('test', () => {
    require('moment-timezone').__setWeekday(3)
    expect(sendModule.send()).toBe(3)
})
```

Do note that manually providing the mock per test file can get tedious and repetitive if the module being mocked has a huge API surface. To address the latter case, you can consider authoring some manual mocks to make them reusable (i.e. using the `__mocks__` directory convention) and supplement that by using [`jest.genMockFromModule()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestgenmockfrommodulemodulename).

[The Jest documentation has some guidance about this.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)